# scheme expand function

Tags: recursion, scheme

I've been trying to solve this problem for hours.
function expand that takes a list of elements and frequencies and expands them into a simple list. For example, the result of (expand '(a (3 b) (3 a) b (2 c) (3 a)) should be (a b b b a a a b c c a a a)

Here is my solution:

---

helper function:

```
(define (expandHelper n value)
  (if (= 0 n) 
      '()
      (cons (append (cons value '()))(expandHelper (- n 1) value))))
```

---

the expand function

```
(define (expand lst) 
  (cond ((null? lst) '())
    (else (expandHelper (car lst) (cadr lst)))))
```

---

But, it doesn't do what I expected it to do. It looks for an integer when the list only has one element which is the value. For example, (expand '(a (2 b)). Since there is only one copy of a, it doesn't have (1 a) in the expression. I am new to Scheme. I would really appreciate it if you could help me.

Thanks

Here is an updated version: But's it's still not right. I would really appreciate it if someone would help me modify my code to get the right results.

```
;; helper function
(define (expandHelper value)
  (if (= 0 value) 
      '()
      (cons (append (cons (car sublist) '()))(expandHelper (- (car sublist) 1) (car sublist)))))  

;; the expand function
(define (expand lst) 
  (cond ((null? lst) '())
        (else (list? (car lst)) (expandHelper (car lst)) (expand (cadr lst)))))
```

Comment: maybe im just being difficult, but what are `a` `b` and `c`?  Are they identifiers?  just stand-ins for integer literals in your dicussion?  do you intend them to be quoted and serve as characters?  obviously the function can not be called exactly as you describe

Comment: @jon_darkstar: They're symbols.

Comment: @jon_darkstar: They're symbols, and there's nothing wrong with the way they're being used. Did you miss the quote?

Comment: @dfan: yep =P his function call was fine obviously, ive used it verbatim in my answer below. sorry about that

Comment: prgammer, have you read [The Little Schemer](http://www.amazon.com/Little-Schemer-Daniel-P-Friedman/dp/0262560992)? It's hard to give a concise-but-understandable description of recursion, and this book does a really good job.

Answer (score 1):

This would be my solution, without any helper function, and recursing on sublist (i.e. (3 a) becomes (cons a (expand '(2 a))):

```
#lang racket

(define (expand lst)
  (cond
    ((null? lst) '())
    ((list? (car lst))
     (let ((cnt (caar lst)) (chr (cadar lst)))
       (if (= cnt 0)
           (expand (cdr lst))
           (cons chr (expand (cons (list (- cnt 1) chr) (cdr lst)))))))
    (else (cons (car lst) (expand (cdr lst))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can express it as a right-fold, and avoid developing a custom recursive function.  If the next element is a list like `(3 a)`, expand and prepend it.  If a symbol, just `cons` it.

```
(define (expand xs)
  (fold-right
   (lambda (x result)
     (if (list? x)
     (append (apply make-list x) result)
         (cons x result)))
   '()
   xs))
```

Comment: This is so elegant I did a double take. I like the use of make-list.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you should think about here. The first is the one you mentioned-- that you could have either `a` or `(1 a)`, both meaning the same thing. You probably want to move that into `expandHelper`, so it looks more like `(expandHelper value)`, and then you should switch on whether it's a list or a symbol.

The second is in how you're calling `expandHelper`. If you feed in a list like `'(a (3 b) (3 a) b (2 c) (3 a))` to `expand`, it'll currently call `(expandHelper a (3 b))`, which is probably not what you had in mind. Instead, you want to make sure you call `expandHelper` on every element of the list, and `cons` together the results. You can do that by calling `expandHelper` on the first element of the list, and then recursively calling `expand` on the remainder of the list.

I haven't checked to see that this compiles, it's just the general idea:

```
(define (expandHelper value)
    (if (list? value) ;; means value is something like (2 a)

        (if (= 0 (car value)) ;; then (car value) is 2
            '() ;; if it's zero, we complete the list and return!
            (cons (cadr value) ;;otherwise, we append (cadr value) = a to...
                  (expandHelper (cons (- (car value) 1) (cadr value))))))
                  ;; the result of expand helper on (- (car value) 1) = 1 
                  ;; and (cadr value) = a

         (cons value '()))) ;; if it's not a list, we should just return the value.
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking too, but, I'm not sure how to implement it. Im new to Scheme and a bit confused too. Im not sure how to change expandHelper.

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (term-expander n val partial)
  (if (zero? n)
    partial
    (term-expander (- n 1) val (cons val partial))))

(define (append-expand a b)
  (if (pair? b)
    (append a (term-expander (car b) (cadr b) '()))
    (append a (list b))))

(define (expand l) (foldl append-expand l '() ))

> (expand '(a (3 b) (3 a) b (2 c) (3 a)))
(a b b b a a a b c c a a a)
```

So... `term-expander` takes `(5 a)` -> `'(a a a a a)'`.  `append-expand` will append the newest term (expanded iff it is a pair) to our answer in progress.  just need to fold this over the list.

I'd hope you have a `foldl` already, but heres mine just in case.

```
(define (foldl op seq init)
  (define (iter acc rest)
    (if (null? rest)
      acc
      (iter (op acc (car rest)) (cdr rest))))
  (iter init seq))
```

---

### EDIT

Realized afterwards this is can be done a LITTLE bit more naturally with `foldr` rather than `foldl` (will need `append-expand` written differently).  Why don't you see if you can find it?  Same idea mostly, but it will operate on the list from back to front and lends itself more naturally to `cons` structures

---

Here's me doing it without fold, but it works the same way and i dont really care for it

```
(define (term-expander p partial)
  (if (zero? (car p))
    partial
    (term-expander (cons (- (car p) 1) (cdr p)) (cons (cadr p) partial))))

(define (expand l)
  (define (expand-rec l partial)
    (if (null? l)
      partial
      (let ((t 
        (if (pair? (car l))
             (term-expander (car l) '())
             (list (car l)))))
      (expand-rec (cdr l) (append partial t)))))
  (expand-rec l '()))

> (expand '(a (3 b) (3 a) b (2 c) (3 a)))
(a b bb a a a b c c a a a)
```

If you would prefer, the `(if (pair?...` section could go in to `term-expander` instead, and then you'd just call it across the board.  I slightly prefer this way but its all the same

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using higher order functions?

Comment: sure, but you'll really just be doing the equivalent of it.  if you choose to do it that way it will probably come more naturally if you put that `(if (pair?...` stuff into `term-expander`

Comment: actually scratch that.  i would only call it on pairs to begin with

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there a way to modify expandHelper to get the same result? a couple of functions maybe? maybe I'm just confused. I was trying to have a helper function that expands each list.

Comment: isnt that `term-expander`? i posted a new one without using `fold`, but i dont particularly care for it and i dont see any way to significantly change it (only superficial choices like let vs if and stuff like that) and of course the directional (forward/back AKA iter/rec), which is equivalent to choosing between foldr and foldl

Answer (score 0):

```
 (define (expand l)
   (cond ((null? l) '())
         ((not (pair? (car l))) (cons (car a) (expand (cdr l)))
         ((< (caar l) 1) (expand (cdr l)))
         (else (cons (cadar l)) (expand (cons (cons (- (caar l) 1) (cdar l))
                                                (cdr l))))))
```